# Problema bucles y void

Tags: c++, while, booleano

Necesito hacer un programa al que le des una cantidad de filas y que me de así:
Fila 1: 1
Fila 2: 1 2
Fila 3: 1 2 3
Fila 4: 1 2 3 4 Así hasta la fila N.
Por cierto, soy bastante nuevo, así que necesito algún consejo para saber como usar el void con las funciones en este tipos de ocasiones, acá hice lo máximo que pude, corríjanme todo lo que quieran, gracias.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void DibujarFilas(int N);

int main () {
    int n;
    cout << "Digite numero de filas: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    DibujarFilas(n);
    return 0;
}

void DibujarFilas(int N) {
    
    int n = 1;
    int k;
    bool fin = false;
    while(!fin) {
        cout << N << " ";
        if(N == k) fin = true;
        N++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El parámetro `void` significa `vacío`, es decir, que no requiere nada. Esto sirve para parámetro o retorno de una función.

Si tienes una definición de función del siguiente modo: `void funcion(int N)` significa que tu función necesita como entrada un entero y que no va a retornar ningún valor. En este caso deberás implementar su llamada como `funcion(variable_de_tipo_int);`.

En cambio, si tuvieses una función declarada como `void funcion(void)` significa que tu función no necesita parámetro de entrada y tampoco te va a retornar ningún valor. En este caso deberás implementar su llamada como `funcion();`.

Por último, si tuvieses una función declarada como `int función(void)`significa que tu función no necesita parámetro de entrada pero que te retornará un entero (en este caso, deberás implementar dicho retorno dentro de tu función mediante `return`). En este caso deberás implementar su llamada como `variable_de_tipo_int = funcion();`.

Por otro lado, el ejemplo que comentas se puede resolver de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void DibujarFilas(int N);

int main() {
    int n;

    cout << "Digite numero de filas: " << endl;
    cin >> n;

    DibujarFilas(n);

    return 0;
}

void DibujarFilas(int N) {
    int  k = 0;
    bool fin = false;
    int  contador = 1;

    for (k = 1; k < N + 1; k++) {
        cout << "Fila " << k << ": ";

        while (!fin) {
            cout << contador << " ";
            if (contador == k)
                fin = true;
            contador++;
        }
        fin = false;
        contador = 1;
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.